# pyspark explode out records based on hierarchy

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, hierarchy

I have the following dataframe:

```
data  = [("A",None, 1, 'Highest'),("B","A", 2, 'High'),("C","B", 3, 'Low'),("D","B", 3, 'Low'), ("X","A", 2, 'High'),("Y","X", 3, 'Low'),("Z","Y", 4, 'Lowest')]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema = ['ID','ParentID','Hierarchy','HierarchyName'])
df.show(truncate=False)
```

[image]

Basically ID **C** and **D** have the same parent which is **B**, which has a parent of **A**.

Similarly ID **Z** has a parent of **Y**, which has a parent of **X**, which has a parent of **A**

For the records at the lowest level, i.e. those which cannot be the ParentID of any other records (ID **C**, **D** and **Z** in this example), important to note here that it's not always just the record with the largest Hierarchy (so not just ID **Z** since its Hierarchy is **4**), how can I turn the dataframe into the following using pyspark?

[image]

I thought about maybe it'd be possible to somehow do multiple joins to get the route from the bottom to the top into an array first:
[image]

```
data1  = [("C",[["3", "Low"],["2", "High"],["1", "Highest"]]),("D",[["3", "Low"],["2", "High"],["1", "Highest"]]),("Z",[["4", "Lowest"],["3", "Low"],["2", "High"],["1", "Highest"]])]
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data=data1, schema = ['ID','HierarchyDefinition'])
df1.show(truncate=False)
```

Then use the explode function:

```
df2 = df1.withColumn("HierarchyDefinition",explode(df1.HierarchyDefinition))
df3 = df2.select("ID", df2.HierarchyDefinition[0].alias("Hierarchy"), df2.HierarchyDefinition[1].alias("HierarchyName"))
df3.show(truncate=False)
```

[image]